# Созданиии истории вызова компонентов Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, frontend

Такой вопрос есть одностраничное приложение на Vue / Nuxt, есть взможность сделать некую глобальныую историю / роутинг вызова компонентов, что бы она была доступна во всех копонентах?
Зачем это нужно, для реализации фукционала вперед, назад стрелочки, не хочется при каждом клике нагромождать разное, как то сделать централизованную историю, и обращаться к ней которая будет отдавать правильные компонент для вызова..
Может есть какие то плагины или что подобное?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать плагин, c объектом истории)
https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins#providing-helpers